# I can't install it

Tags: crash, install, lenovo

I downloaded it to a USB and used Rufus to make it an ISO. I put it in another computer and when I choose install, there are no options to download the OS, then it crashes and opens the tryal version.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but I assume that you downloaded elementary OS and wrote a bootable USB using Rufus.

In the process Rufus might have asked you two option to write in `iso` or `dd`.Use both and. Finally check the USB by ticking the check option in Rufus.

I think the iso image might be corrupted due to incomplete download.